# Can't deploy a firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I want to deploy the next cloud function however I'm unable of do it:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.pushNotifications = functions.database.ref("/ingresos/{docId}").onCreate(
    (snapshot, context) => {
         admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
            "new_ingreso",
            {
                notification: {
                    title: 'some title',
                    body: 'some body'
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Error:

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        pushNotifications(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

I just taked this example but it uses Firestore database but I want use the realtime database..

```
exports.pushNotifications = functions.firestore.document("Notifications/{docId}").onCreate(
    (snapshot, context) => {
         admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
            "new_posts",
            {
                notification: {
                    title: "A New Notification",
                    body: "Hello World!"
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I want to deploy the first cloud function of this question. In this cloud function I want to send a notificacion to the clients by using firebase messaging.

My realtime database has this structure:

[image]

I also tried do something like this but nothing happens:

```
exports.pushNotifications = functions.database.ref("/ingresos/{docId}")
    .onCreate(event => {
         admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
            "new_ingreso",
            {
                notification: {
                    title: 'some title',
                    body: 'some body'
                }
            }
        );
    })
```

Any idea for fix this problem dears I will appreciate it.
Thanks so much.

Comment: I just chaged the name of this function and worked and the old function was deleted.

Comment: Hello Freddict, could you add your comment as an answer, spicifying the previous command and the current, and all the possible changes that could cause that the deploy worked. I will be more than happy to upvote your answer.